# Symfony2 Domain separated bundles

Tags: php, apache, symfony, routes, cross-domain

I would like to know if there's a way to use a domain name for each bundle I have in my symfony2 app, for example

```
WebFooBundle => www.foobundle.com
WebBarBundle => www.barbundle.com
```

My routes are for example `localhost/foo/` and `localhost/bar/` so www.foobundle.com needs to call `/foo` and www.barbundle.com points to `/bar`

I want to use this method, if possible, because I don't want to create a new Symfony2 structure for each page :S I want a whole Application made in Symfony2 with bundles (that's the point of Symfony2!!)

I have this on my `app/config/routing.yml`

```
web_foo:
    host: "foo.com"
    prefix:   /
    resource: "@WebFooBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
web_bar:
    host: "bar.com"
    prefix:   /
    resource: "@WebBarBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

So now, when I enter to `foo.com` the homepage for `WebFooBundle` loads perfectly, **BUT** if I go to `www.foo.com` i get a white page on PROD, on DEV I just get `No route found for "GET /"`

How can I handle www.domain.com and domain.com in my route?

Also, there is another problem...

if I go to `foo.com/faq` on PROD, I get 404 error, on DEV it displays my FAQ page...

What is wrong!! I just want to have on the same folder, just one symfony2 app with multiple bundles binded to multiple domains (one domain per bundle) :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using `host`

```
mobile_homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     m.example.com
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:mobileHomepage }

homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage }
```

[DOC](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, what I need to config in Apache? Because it now points to /web/app.php which is the default... but as I said I need to use `/web/app.php/mysite` and use it with `www.mydomain.com` only

Comment: You need configure alias for base doman ( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)  or configure VirtualHost ( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html )  
but VirtualHost are not good idea for that. If You has many domain for one symfony "instance" which are with many bundles create aliases for it